# Find objects that start with the same value and keep only the longest value in the array Powershell

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, path, duplicates

I am trying to find a solution to filter my array.

For the criterion it would be: if an object of the 3rd column matches (or contains) with another object of this same column. Then delete it.

Here is an example of $data:

```
By      Mode File
--      ---- ----
user1   Read creation\1. ABC
user1   Read creation\1. ABC\Invoice
user1   Read creation\1. ABC\LIMITED
user2   Read edition\File
user2   Read edition\File\DATA SHEETS
user2   Read BCD
user2   Read BCD\DATA
user3   Read BCD
```

I want to delete the objects which have an identical beginning by keeping only the one which has the most characters.
However, if it is not the same user, the line should not be filtered.

what I am looking for as a result :

```
By      Mode File
--      ---- ----
user1   Read creation\1. ABC\Invoice
user1   Read creation\1. ABC\LIMITED
user2   Read edition\File\DATA SHEETS
user2   Read BCD\DATA
user3   Read BCD
```

What I tried :

```
foreach($elem in $data.file)
{
$data.file.Where({$_.contains($elem)}, 'First',3)
}
```

I am stuck, thank you for your comments

Comment: I want to keep "user2   Read BCD\DATA" and delete "user2   Read BCD" because it's like a duplicate

Comment: it is not easy to explain. I want to filter my array. For that I want to delete the objects which have an identical beginning by keeping only the one which has the most characters.
Sorry for the wobbly explanations.

Comment: You are going to have to use break/parse down the length of that third column, and as Olaf is pointing out use the Group-By on that result.

Comment: For the criterion it would be: if an object of the 3rd column matches (or contains) with another object of this same column. Then delete it.

Comment: thank you for trying and encouraging me to improve to detail better.
This string "user2   Read BCD" exists in this one "user2   Read BCD\DATA". So I want to delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the helpful comments, I believe this is what you're looking for, assuming we have the example input stored in a variable called CSV:

```bash
$csv = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
By,Mode,File
user1,Read,creation\1. ABC
user1,Read,creation\1. ABC\Invoice
user1,Read,creation\1. ABC\LIMITED
user2,Read,edition\File
user2,Read,edition\File\DATA SHEETS
user2,Read,BCD
user2,Read,BCD\DATA
user3,Read,BCD
'@
```

We can use a combination of [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.3), [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.3) and [`String.StartsWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-8.0):

```bash
# group the objects by the `By` property and enumerate them
$csv | Group-Object By | ForEach-Object {
    # sort the groups by the `File` property (ascending)
    $sorted = @($_.Group | Sort-Object File)
    # and enumerate each group
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $sorted.Count; $i++) {
        # store the current item
        $current = $sorted[$i]
        # and the next item in this collection
        $next = $sorted[$i + 1]
        # if there is a next item in this group AND
        # the next item `File` property starts with the same string as the current item
        # i.e.: `'edition\File\DATA SHEETS'.StartsWith('edition\File')`
        if($next -and $next.File.StartsWith($current.File, [StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
            # we can assume this one can be skipped
            continue
        }
        # else, output it
        $current
    }
}
```

The produced output from this example would be:

```
By    Mode File
--    ---- ----
user1 Read creation\1. ABC\Invoice
user1 Read creation\1. ABC\LIMITED
user2 Read BCD\DATA
user2 Read edition\File\DATA SHEETS
user3 Read BCD
```

Comment: really impressive. huge thanks
The production test works perfectly. 
There is something to love about powershell!

Comment: @Cora_beeetle ❤️ it is a great language for sure! There is something to love about .NET too hehe.

Comment: ***Santiago Squarzon*** for the win. ;-}... but know this is a PowerShellCore-only thing. Windows PS5x does not like it. ;-} It just screams at you complaining about ```Index was outside the bounds of the array.```  for each user.  This was what I was working, you know trying to ensure cross-platform and backwards compact (just in case the poster was stuck on legacy PS),  ***Santiago Squarzon*** posted.

Comment: @postanote thanks but are you sure this is 7+ only? this works fine for me in 5.1. might only fail if using strict mode otherwise it works in both versions ;)

Comment: I did a test on two of my PS5x machines, and it did fail on both. As a rule, I always have ```StrictMode``` in all my developer machine profiles. You know, just to keep me in check as I code. ;-}   I just executed this on my default Windows Sandbox, no profile settings, then this works as expected.

Comment: @postanote yeah makes sense it would fail on StrictMode. I personally never use it